# Xamarin Forms - Get the size of an AbsoluteLayout

Tags: height, width

I cannot find the way to get the `Width` and the `Height` of a `Xamarin.Forms.View`.

I have this object:

```
public class SquareLayout : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScalingBaseProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ScalingBase), typeof(ScalingBaseType), typeof(SquareLayout), ScalingBaseType.Average,
            propertyChanged: OnScalingBasePropertyChanged);

    public ScalingBaseType ScalingBase
    {
        get { return (ScalingBaseType)GetValue(ScalingBaseProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScalingBaseProperty, value); }
    }

    public enum ScalingBaseType
    {
        Average,
        Height,
        Width
    }

    public static void OnScalingBasePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        SquareLayout sq = ((SquareLayout)bindable);

        Debug.WriteLine("|Width = {0}|Height = {1}|", sq.Bounds.Width, sq.Bounds.Height);

        switch (sq.ScalingBase)
        {
            case ScalingBaseType.Average:
                double size = (sq.Bounds.Width + sq.Bounds.Height) / 2;
                sq.WidthRequest = size;
                sq.HeightRequest = size;
                break;
            case ScalingBaseType.Height:
                sq.WidthRequest = sq.Bounds.Height;
                break;
            case ScalingBaseType.Width:
                sq.HeightRequest = sq.Bounds.Width;
                break;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("|Width = {0}|Height = {1}|", sq.Bounds.Width, sq.Bounds.Height);
    }
}
```

Basically, you declare somewhere this SquareLayout and then, based on an `Enum`, the layout is resized as a **Square**.

So, I then have this **XAML part**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
  <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White">
  ...
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ToolsLayout" BackgroundColor="Red"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.05, 0.9, 0.075"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
      <control:SquareLayout BackgroundColor="White" ScalingBase="Height"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0.5, 0.1, 1"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

      </control:SquareLayout>
      <control:SquareLayout BackgroundColor="White" ScalingBase="Height"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0.5, 0.1, 1"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

      </control:SquareLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
  ...
  </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Which would give me a `Rectangle` with two `Square` around.. But nothing !

I tried to display the `Width` and the `Height` but nothing.. I tried the `Bounds` as well as you can see in the example, but nothing one more time..

The only values I get are **-1**

Does someone can help me? Thank in advance !

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? You can answer your own question

Comment: Not really :/ sorry

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has very less documentation for newbies , took some time to figure this out , basically during design time the the width and height property have a default value of -1 , which indicates auto , there is no way of knowing during design time what the values will be , hence you need to use 'events' to get the width and height property in this case you will use SizeChanged event , when the layout bounds are set during runtime this event will trigger.

In your xaml codebehind use this event to get your widh and height of yourlayout , i have used a lambda function , this can be implemented in many ways i just find this method easy.

```
yourlayout.SizeChanged+=(sender,e)=>
{
//Add your child objects here and set its values using yourlayout.Height etc
};
```

Instead of adding your children within this function you can use it to return a value and use that instead.

NOTE:I am not sure if this is the best practice for MVVM or otherwise